# How to link batch-response entries with the request entries in FHIR (DSTU3)

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am currently building an application for which it is important to check the existence of resources with a certain profile.

As we need to check this for 40+ profiles I'd like to put this all in 1 batch request and let our HAPI-FHIR server implementation handle this, as opposed to querying them one by one. This would get too chatty otherwise.

Because I only need to know about whether the resource exists I'd like to use `_summary=count`. I am assuming this increases the performance of the request.

**Example request**

```json
{
  "resourceType": "Bundle",
  "type": "batch",
  "entry": [
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/Observation?_profile=http://nictiz.nl/fhir/StructureDefinition/zib-DrugUse&_summary=true"
      }
    },
    {
      "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/RelatedPerson?_profile=http://fhir.nl/fhir/StructureDefinition/nl-core-relatedperson&_summary=count"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Response**

```json
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "fd66cfd9-4693-496d-86fc-98289067480b",
    "type": "batch-response",
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "<redacted>"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Bundle",
                "id": "2647a49f-0503-496b-b274-07d4e9163f1b",
                "meta": {
                    "lastUpdated": "2021-02-15T11:44:18.035+00:00",
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/ObservationValue",
                            "code": "SUBSETTED",
                            "display": "Resource encoded in summary mode"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "searchset",
                "total": 48
            },
            "response": {
                "status": "200 OK"
            }
        },
        {
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Bundle",
                "id": "2f9cc861-5d20-4da1-aa9f-12153b75539d",
                "meta": {
                    "lastUpdated": "2021-02-15T11:44:18.151+00:00",
                    "tag": [
                        {
                            "system": "http://hl7.org/fhir/v3/ObservationValue",
                            "code": "SUBSETTED",
                            "display": "Resource encoded in summary mode"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "type": "searchset",
                "total": 10
            },
            "response": {
                "status": "200 OK"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I assume that the ordering of the batch-response is the same as that of the batch-request?

Or is there a method to annotate the batch entries which are persisted onto the batch-response?

Or finally, is there a flag I can turn on to make the response include the `request.url` part?

I'm using HAPI-FHIR 5.1.0 both for client and server.

Comment: Be aware that the search you're doing will just tell you if the resource *declares* the profile, not find everything that conforms.  It's theoretically possible (though non-conformant) for something to declare support for a profile it doesn't comply with.  It's also quite possible (even common) for an instance to comply with profiles it doesn't declare.  Unfortunately, there's no efficient way to search for those, though if you have candidates, you can use the $validate operation to test them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I didn't look well enough in the specs, as I just found the following:

**From the [FHIR spec](http://hl7.org/fhir/STU3/http.html#transaction-response)**

*For a batch, or a successful transaction, the response the server SHALL return a Bundle with type set to batch-response or transaction-response that contains one entry for each entry in the request, **in the same order**, with the outcome of processing the entry.*